# NetCDF get_dims too many values to unpack

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, netcdf, netcdf4

I am working with a NetCDF file (.nc) - 600+MB.

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import num2date
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

# Open netCDF4 file
file_location = '2m dewpoint temperature.nc'
f = netCDF4.Dataset(file_location)
```

In order to convert the file to CSV I started by finding its attributes

```
# Find the attributes
print(f.variables.keys())

Output: dict_keys(['longitude', 'latitude', 'expver', 'time', 'd2m'])
```

Then, extracted the variable and when trying to get the dimensions

```
# Extract variable
d2m = f.variables['d2m']
 
# Get dimensions
time_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim = d2m.get_dims()
time_var = f.variables[time_dim.name]
times = num2date(time_var[:], time_var.units)
latitudes = f.variables[lat_dim.name][:]
longitudes = f.variables[lon_dim.name][:]
```

I am getting the following error

> time_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim = d2m.get_dims()
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

What is happening here and how should I solve it?

---

**Edit 1**

The output of `print(d2m.get_dims())` is

```
(<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 94750, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'expver', size = 2, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'latitude', size = 33, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'longitude', size = 53)
```

---

**Edit 2**

`df.head()` for [@RobertWilson's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64569041/7109869)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@user2856 said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377672/netcdf-get-dims-too-many-values-to-unpack/377727#comment617261_377672), I was getting the number of dims the tuple unpacking code was expecting.

In order to get the right amount of dims, I ran

```
print(d2m.get_dims())
```

The output was

```
(<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'time', size = 94750, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'expver', size = 2, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'latitude', size = 33, <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension'>: name = 'longitude', size = 53)
```

Therefore I just adjusted the line that was giving error to

```
time_dim, expver_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim = d2m.get_dims()
```

Then everything ran smoothly, including the conversion to .CSV.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have more than 3 dimensions. As a result this should fail:

```
time_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim = d2m.get_dims()
```

You just need to check what `d2m.get_dims()` gives you then amend the line.

A quicker way to convert to csv would be using xarray:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
ds = xr.open_dataset(file_location)
df = ds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
# subset the dataframe etc.    
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: thank you, [already solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570295/7109869). Your solution, with some tweaks, may also work. For the d2m.get_dims() output, check Edit 1 in the question. As for the way you suggested to convert to csv, the df gives me the following error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.47 GiB for an array with shape (331435500,) and data type int64`. I tried a smiliar sample before without the `.reset_index()` and the output is a df with size (33145500, 1), which is too big to open locally. Check Edit 2 for the `df.head()`.

Comment: Looks like a RAM issue. Potentially more data being unpacked than you need. But if you have a solution, never search for a simpler one...